# i18next parse Regex OR operator

Tags: regex, i18next

I have the following regex string

`{{t\s+(?:\"((?:[^\\\\\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*)\"|'(?:[^'\\\\]|\\\\.)*')?([^}]*)}}`

which successfully takes a handlebars string `{{t "Some key"}}` and creates an output

`{"Some key": ""}` using command

`i18next index.handlebars -p "{{t\s+(?:\"((?:[^\\\\\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*)\"|'(?:[^'\\\\]|\\\\.)*')?([^}]*)}}" --locales en,zh --output ../locales`

Now I also want to be able to parse javascript functions like t('some key') with the same output. I know the regex string for this is

`[^a-zA-Z0-9_](?:t)(?:\\(|\\s)\\s*(?:(?:\'((?:(?:\\\\\')?[^\']+)+[^\\\\])\')|(?:"((?:(?:\\\\"‌​)?[^"]+)+[^\\\\])"))/g`

But when I try placing both regex strings in brackets separated by a pipe I get an error about an unexpected bracket -

`i18next index.handlebars -p "(?:{{t\s+(?:\"((?:[^\\\\\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*)\"|'(?:[^'\\\\]|\\\\.)*')?([^}]*)}})|(?:[^a-zA-Z0-9_](?:t)(?:\\(|\\s)\\s*(?:(?:\'((?:(?:\\\\\')?[^\']+)+[^\\\\])\')|(?:"((?:(?:\\\\"‌​)?[^"]+)+[^\\\\])"))/g)" --locales en,zh --output ../locales`

Comment: You do seem to have a missing `)`. Something like so: `(?:{{t\s+(?:\"((?:[^\\\\\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*)\"|'(?:[^'\\\\]|\\\\.)*')?([^}]*)}})
|(?:[^a-zA-Z0-9_](?:t)(?:\\(|\\s)\\s*(?:(?:\'((?:(?:\\\\\')?[^\']+)+[^\\\\])\'))
|(?:"((?:(?:\\\\"‌​)?[^"]+)+[^\\\\])"))/g)` seems to fix the issue, bit considering the length of the expression it's difficult to see if it is what you are after.

Comment: @npinti using that regex I get 'Syntax error: "(" unexpected'

Comment: What about `"(?:{{t\s+(?:\"((?:[^\\\\\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*)\"|'(?:[^'\\\\]|\\\\.)*')?([^}]*)}})|(?:[^a-zA-Z0-9_](?:t)(?:\\(|\\s)\\s*(?:(?:\'((?:(?:\\\\\')?[^\']+)+[^\\\\])\')|(?:"((?:(?:\\\\"‌​)?[^"]+)+[^\\\\])")))/g"`?

Comment: I think you can use `\\{\\{t\\s*(?:\\(?\"((?:[^\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*)\"|'(?:[^'\\\\]|\\\\.)*')?([^}]*)}}`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wS3qF1/2).

Comment: @npinti that produces the same error

Comment: @stribizhev you are missing the right hand side of the OR operator

Comment: Aha, I was more focused on the first example. As for the second, you might try `(?:{{t\\s+(?:\"((?:[^\\\\\"]|\\\\.)*)\"|\'(?:[^\'\\\\]|\\\\.)*\')?([^}]*)}})|(?:[^a-zA-Z0-9_](?:t)(?:\\(|\\s)\\s*(?:(?:\'((?:(?:\\\\\')?[^\']+)+[^\\\\])\')|(?:\"((?:(?:\\\\\"‌​)?[^\"]+)+[^\\\\])\")))`. See [updated demo](https://regex101.com/r/wS3qF1/3). I noticed you have inconsistent escaping in your regex (sometimes, `"` is not escaped, and `\s` is only escaped once in the beginning.) Try escaping with ``\\`` all special characters and `'` and `"` just once.

Comment: @stribizhev Thanks. That runs without error and I can see it working in the fiddle example. Strangely it is still not matching the i18n.t('key') strings in my js files. The {{t 'key'}} strings are correctly being matched.

Comment: Well, it works [here](https://regex101.com/r/wS3qF1/5)... :(